# Slow MySQL InnoDB Inserts and Updates

Tags: mysql, magento, innodb

I am using magento and having a lot of slowness on the site.  There is very, very light load on the server.  I have verified cpu, disk i/o, and memory is light- less than 30% of available at all times.  APC caching is enabled- I am using new relic to monitor the server and the issue is very clearly insert/updates.

I have isolated the slowness to all insert and update statements.  SELECT is fast.  Very simple insert / updates into tables take 2-3 seconds whether run from my application or the command line mysql.

Example:

```
UPDATE `index_process` SET `status` = 'working', `started_at` = '2012-02-10 19:08:31' WHERE (process_id='8');
```

This table has 9 rows, a primary key, and 1 index on it.

The slowness occurs with all insert / updates.  I have run mysqltuner and everything looks good.  Also, changed innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit to 2.

The activity on this server is very light- it's a dv box with 1 GB RAM.  I have magento installs that run 100x better with 5x the load on a similar setup.

I started logging all queries over 2 seconds and it seems to be all inserts and full text searches.

Anyone have suggestions?

Here is table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `index_process` (  
  `process_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `indexer_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
   `status` enum('pending','working','require_reindex') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',  
  `started_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
  `ended_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
  `mode` enum('real_time','manual') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'real_time',  
  PRIMARY KEY (`process_id`),  
  UNIQUE KEY `IDX_CODE` (`indexer_code`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

Comment: With the EAV model, Magento is slow by design.

Comment: I'm aware of slowness of EAV model.  This issue is not related to EAV tables.  I have magento running very well on other servers.

Comment: It was just my Friday troll ;) Have you tried to do an EXPLAIN on the query that you suspect to be slow ?

Comment: Yes, but the main issue is with inserts- i don't think explain works with insert / update.  Does it work?

Comment: Try measure time of next query sequence `ALTER TABLE $tbl_name DISABLE KEYS`, run your query and `ALTER TABLE $tbl_name ENABLE KEYS`. If it is much faster than you need do something with table indexes.

Comment: I do not agree with EAV being the issue as very very few of my performance issues with Magento have ever had to do with EAV. I would argue the custom built framework on top of Zend is much more inefficient. The table outlined above is not even EAV in nature.

Anyhow - 
If you issue the query directly to MySQL on the command line do you also see 1-2 second insert times?

Comment: Are you using serializable transactions or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

First: `(process_id='8')` - `'8'` is `char/varchar`, not `int`, so mysql convert value first.

On my system, I had long times (greater than one second) to update users.last_active_time.

The reason was that I had a few queries that long to perform. As I joined them for the users table. This resulted in blocking of the table to read. Death lock by SELECT.

I rewrote query from: JOIN to: sub-queries and porblem gone.